# Manual Assembly vs GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Disclaimer: I'm just starting out with x86 assembly. I did learn a bit of SPIM at university, but that's hardly worth mentioning.

I thought I start with what's probably the most simple function in libc, abs(). Pretty straightforward in C:

```
long myAbs(long j) {
    return j < 0 ? -j : j;
}
```

My version in assembly:

```
    .global myAbs
    .type   myAbs, @function
    .text

myAbs:
    test %rdi, %rdi
    jns end
    negq %rdi
end:
    movq %rdi, %rax
    ret
```

(This doesn't work for 32bit integers, probably because RAX is a 64bit register and the sign is probably at the wrong position - I have to investigate that).

Now here's what gcc does (gcc -O2 -S myAbs.c):

```
        .file   "myAbs.c"
        .section        .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB0:
        .text
.LHOTB0:
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  myAbs
        .type   myAbs, @function
myAbs:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $4144, %rsp
        orq     $0, (%rsp)
        addq    $4128, %rsp
        movq    %rdi, %rdx
        sarq    $63, %rdx
        movq    %fs:40, %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        xorq    %rdx, %rax
        subq    %rdx, %rax
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
        xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
        jne     .L5
        leave
        .cfi_remember_state
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
.L5:
        .cfi_restore_state
        call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   myAbs, .-myAbs
        .section        .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE0:
        .text
.LHOTE0:
        .ident  "GCC: (Gentoo Hardened 5.1.0 p1.2, pie-0.6.3) 5.1.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Why this big difference? GCC produces substantially more instructions. I can't imagine that this won't be slower than my code.
Am I missing something? Or am I doing something seriousely wrong here?

Comment: Maybe your GCC is feeling unwell? Mine produces [fewer instructions](https://goo.gl/wG2v1X). (And Clang likes [conditional moves](https://goo.gl/xpxKyi).)

Comment: "GCC: (Gentoo Hardened 5.1.0 p1.2, pie-0.6.3) 5.1.0" - I think this is the clue. The hardened C compiler incorporates stack-smashing protection or something similar.

Comment: Many of the begginning calls are to setup the stack and save the return address (something which you are not doing). Seems like theres are some stack protection going on. Perhaps you could tune your compiler settings to get rid of some overhead.

Comment: Ooops you're right. I used the hardened compiler, as soon as I switch to the vanilla one it works (both with gcc 4.9.3 and 5.1.0). Thanks!

Comment: FWIW compilers will usually try to avoid branches (jumps) as they can be expensive on modern processors. The 3-instructions that Clang produces seem pretty optimal to me.

Comment: @cabellicar123: Shame, it seems like the compiler should figure out that this is a leaf function and doesn't need stack protection.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because the weird compiler output comes from you accidentally using the wrong compiler.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the fact that it's a leaf function doesn't eliminate the need for stack protection, it could still contain a buffer overflow.  (In this case the function is too simple for that to be an issue, but presumably under normal circumstances the compiler would inline it instead.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Hm, yes, good point -- I think I meant that the compiler should be able to see that this function doesn't modify the stack?

Comment: @KerrekSB: true; a leaf function with with no local variables and no need to spill arguments presumably doesn't need stack protection.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For those who wonder what the generated code comes from, first note that when GCC compile `myAbs` with stack protection it transform it into this form

```
long myAbs(long j) {
    uintptr_t canary = __stack_chk_guard;

    register long result = j < 0 ? -j : j;

    if ( (canary = canary ^ __stack_chk_guard) != 0 )
        __stack_chk_fail();
}
```

The code to simply perform `j < 0 ? -j : j;` is

```
movq    %rdi, %rdx     ;RDX = j
movq    %rdi, %rax     ;RAX = j
sarq    $63, %rdx      ;RDX = 0 if j >=0, 0fff...ffh if j < 0
xorq    %rdx, %rax     ;Note: x xor 0ff...ffh = Not X, x xor 0 = x
                       ;RAX = j if j >=0, ~j if j < 0
subq    %rdx, %rax     ;Note: 0fff...ffh = -1
                       ;RAX = j+0 = j if j >= 0, ~j+1 = -j if j < 0
                       ;~j+1 = -j in two complement
```

Analyzing the generated code we get

```
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp       ;Standard prologue

    subq    $4144, %rsp      ;Allocate slight more than 4 KiB     
    orq     $0, (%rsp)       ;Perform a useless RW operation to test if there is enough stack space for __stack_chk_fail

    addq    $4128, %rsp      ;This leave 16 byte allocated for local vars

    movq    %rdi, %rdx       ;See above
    sarq    $63, %rdx        ;See above

    movq    %fs:40, %rax     ;Get the canary
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)   ;Save it as a local var
    xorl    %eax, %eax       ;Clear it

    movq    %rdi, %rax       ;See above
    xorq    %rdx, %rax       ;See above
    subq    %rdx, %rax       ;See above

    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx   ;RCX = Canary
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx     ;Check if equal to the original value
    jne     .L5              ;If not fail

    leave
    ret
.L5:
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT  ;__stack_chk_fail is noreturn
```

So all the extra instructions are for implementing the [Stack Smashing Protector](http://wiki.osdev.org/Stack_Smashing_Protector).

**Thanks to FUZxxl** for pointing out the use of the first instructions after the prologue.

Comment: The code is subtracting 4144 and then adding 4128 to `%rsp` to make sure that that much extra stack space is available. If it didn't, you could circumvent the stack checking by exhausting the stack first (causing the process to crash for a different reason that is not a failed stack check).

Comment: @FUZxxl Could you elaborate? Do you mean it should protect from a stack overflow? I'm puzzled by that instructions

Comment: Consider the case where the stack is almost full and someone overwrites the canary. In this case, the code might detect that the stack check failed but there is not enough space to run `__stack_chk_fail`, so instead of printing a big-ass warning that the stack check failed, the code just crashes with a segmentation fault, hiding the fact that someone tried to break into the program. The subtraction, write, and addition sequence makes sure that around 4 KiB of stack space remain which should be enough for `__stack_chk_fail` to run.

Answer (score 6):

Many of the beginning calls are to setup the stack and save the return address (something which you are not doing). Seems like theres are some ***stack protection*** going on. Perhaps you could tune your compiler settings to get rid of some overhead.

Perhaps adding flags to you compiler such as: `-fno-stack-protector` could minimise this difference.

Yes this probably is slower than your handwritten assembly, but offers much more protection and is probably worth the slight overhead.

As for why the stack protection still exists even though it is a leaf function [see here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Leaf-Functions.html).